# Prove that the interval $(0,1)$ is a connected topological space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Prove that the interval $(0,1)$ is a connected topological space

My teacher gave us a hint and I want to prove it in his way.

*Hint:* Suppose $(0,1)$ is disconnected, then exists subsets $U,V$, where $U,V$ are non empty, disjoint and relatively open. Pick a point $a\in U,b\in V$. Take the middle point $p$ between $a,b$ and check to which set $p$ belongs.

*Attempt:*

Here $---$ is $\mathbb R$

Some demo:

$---(0---a---p---b---1)---$

then $(a,p)$ or $(p,b)$ one of their edges will be on different sets, we will split again $--(0---a--p1--p--p2--b--1)--$ and again and again...

then we will get a two series of points that converge to some point that this point not in $U$ or $V$

Can someone help me to prove this in my teacher's way?

Comment: What does the sentence "then $(a,p)$ or $(p,b)$ one of their edges will be on different sets" mean?

Comment: You are implicitly assuming $a<b$ to start.  In general I think you just want a sequence of points $a_n$ and $b_n$ (one in $U$, the other in $V$, for each $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$) that satisfy $0 < a_1 \leq a_n \leq b_n \leq  b_1 < 1$ for all $n \in \{1, 2,3, ...\}$, and where $a_n$ and $b_n$ both converge to the same point in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition $U \cup V = (0,1)$.  Thus $U$ and $V$ are also relatively closed.
Using that $U$ and $V$ are open, show that neither sequence is finite.
Next show that both sequences converge to the same point $p$.
Since $U$ and $V$ are closed, $p$ is in $U$ and in $V$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, $(0,1)$ is obviously path connected; since any two points in $(0,1)$ can be joined via a straight line. Hence $(0,1)$ is connected.